# Compare elements by value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I´m trying to compare several divs with a class and a value, only works when i do it with id, can´t figure out how to do it by class name

This isn´t working

```
<body>
<div id="horarios">
<div class="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor</div>
<div class="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor1</div>
<div class="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor2</div>
</div>
<script>
var regex = new RegExp(':', 'g'),
    timeStr1 = '5:50:55',
    timeStr2 = document.getElementById("horarios").classList.contains('demo').getAttribute('value');
if(parseInt(timeStr1.replace(regex, ''), 10) < parseInt(timeStr2.replace(regex, ''), 10)){
  console.log('timeStr1 is smaller then timeStr2');
} else {
  console.log('timeStr2 is smaller then timeStr1');
}
</script>

</body>
```

This is working

```
<body>

<div id="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor</div>

<script>
var regex = new RegExp(':', 'g'),
    timeStr1 = '5:50:55',
    timeStr2 = document.getElementById('demo').getAttribute('value');
if(parseInt(timeStr1.replace(regex, ''), 10) < parseInt(timeStr2.replace(regex, ''), 10)){
  console.log('timeStr1 is smaller then timeStr2');
} else {
  console.log('timeStr2 is smaller then timeStr1');
}
</script>

</body>
```

Thank you

Comment: To get all elements of a class you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.demo')`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `document.getElementsByClassName` instead. Your problem is that the `contains` function returns a Boolean (see the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_contains.asp) for more details). This means that the `getAttribute` cannot work since it expects a Node instead of a Boolean.

This should work:

```
timeStr2 = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
```

Note that this will be an array of elements, so if you only want the value of the first element, use this instead

```
timeStr2 = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].getAttribute("value");
```

Update after seeing the comments. You should use a loop to check every value one after another:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("demo").forEach((currentElement) => {
  const timeString = currentElement.getAttribute("value");

  if (parseInt(timeString .replace(regex, ""), 10) < parseInt(timeString .replace(regex, ""), 10)) {
    console.log(currentElement.innerText + " is smaller than timeStr2");
  } else {
    console.log("timeStr2 is smaller than " + currentElement.innerText);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, how can i do it to get all the elements with the same class to be campared? With your answer i need to change this [0] for every element.

Comment: You would need to use a loop. It's unclear from your question which values you need to compare. Right now, according to your code, you have 4 `timeStr`. Which one should be compared to which other(s)?

Comment: The values that need to be compared is the hour with the hour at the time it runs, i want to display elements only if the hour (right now) didn´t happend, if this happened i want to hide elements

Answer (score 0):

Well it's normal that it doesn't work, as [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) returns a list of the classes of a specific elements, not it's children.

You could use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) for that purpose:

```js
var demos = document.querySelectorAll("div.demo");
```

This would be a list of elements, that you can later on check by classes and whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I misunderstood the question, but to apply the code to any element with the class of `demo`, this should work:

```
<body>
    <div id="horarios">
      <div class="demo" value="5:50:54">Le valor</div>
      <div class="demo" value="5:50:56">Le valor1</div>
      <div class="demo" value="5:50:55">Le valor2</div>
    </div>

    <script>
      const demos = document.querySelectorAll(".demo");

      demos.forEach((demo) => {
        let regex = new RegExp(":", "g");
        let timeStr1 = "5:50:55";
        let timeStr2 = demo.getAttribute("value");

        if (
          parseInt(timeStr1.replace(regex, ""), 10) <
          parseInt(timeStr2.replace(regex, ""), 10)
        ) {
          console.log("timeStr1 is smaller then timeStr2");
        } else {
          console.log("timeStr2 is smaller then timeStr1");
        }
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Happy it worked out. Consider accepting one of the answers on this question so if someone else comes looking for a solution they can see what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**, I Solve you question.

First you can't select element and call `classlist.contains()` Method On Its Childs it must be on the element it self so you can add `querySelectorAll()`
and select div have the class.

This Is You Code Edited

```js
var regex = new RegExp(":", "g"),
  timeStr1 = "5:50:55",
  divsDemo = document.querySelectorAll(".demo");

divsDemo.forEach((div) => {
  let timeStr2 = div.getAttribute("value");
  if (
    parseInt(timeStr1.replace(regex, ""), 10) <
    parseInt(timeStr2.replace(regex, ""), 10)
  ) {
    console.log("timeStr1 is smaller then timeStr2");
  } else {
    console.log("timeStr2 is smaller then timeStr1");
  }
});
```

```html
    <div id="horarios">
      <div class="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor</div>
      <div class="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor1</div>
      <div class="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor2</div>
    </div>
```

I add `forEach` Method to check all the div not first div only

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the elements and compare them one by one:

```js
const regex = new RegExp(':', 'g'),
timeStr1Unformatted = '5:50:55',
els = document.getElementById("horarios").children

Array.from(els).forEach(el => 
{
  const timeStr1 = parseInt(timeStr1Unformatted.replace(regex, ''), 10),
  timeStr2 = parseInt(el.getAttribute('value').replace(regex, ''), 10)
  
  if (timeStr1 < timeStr2) {
    console.log('timeStr1 is smaller then timeStr2');
  } else {
    console.log('timeStr2 is smaller then timeStr1');
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="horarios">
  <div class="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor</div>
  <div class="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor1</div>
  <div class="demo" value="5:40:55">Le valor2</div>
</div>
```